# Prove that $f_n$ has $n$ distinct roots which are symmetric about $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

Given $f_0(x)\equiv 1$ and define $f_n$ recursively via
$$f_{n+1}(x)=xf_n(x)-f'_n(x).$$
Prove that $f_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. Further prove that $f_n$ has $n$ distinct real roots which are symmetric about $0$ (by symmetric we mean that if $a$ is a root of $f_n$, then so is $-a$).

**Work so far:** Proving that $f_n$ is a degree $n$ polynomial is rather easy, this can be done by induction. The difficult part comes from the second part. To show that $f_n$ has $n$distinct roots, I first multiply $e^{-x^2/2}$ on both sides of the recursive equation, and this yields
$$e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}f_{n+1}(x)=(e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}f_n(x))'.$$
Put $g_n(x):=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}f_n(x)$, we see that $g_n$ has a formular
$$g_n(x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}g_0(x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}.$$
Thus the question now is to prove that $g_n$ has $n$ distinct real roots which are symmetric.

To show the roots are symmetric, we may show that the function is symmetric(either about the $y-$axis or the origion). What I really have trouble on is to prove $n$ distinct real roots. I'm not sure if this approach really works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Hint: Show that $f_n$ is a polynomial with terms either all in odd powers or even powers; i.e., either odd or even.*]

From that I guess you can probably see the symmetry.

To show that there are indeed $n$ roots for $f_n$, we use the induction again:

1. *Base Case*: trivial.
2. *Inductive Step*: Suppose $n=k$ the claim is true. Need: $xf_k(x) = f'_k(x)$ happens exactly $k+1$ times. Consider $g_k(x) = f_k(x) e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$. Observation: (i) $g'_k(x) = \left( -xf_k\left( x \right) +f'_k(x)\right )e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} = 0$ if and only if $xf_k(x) = f'_k(x)$; (ii) the number of roots of $g_k$ is exacty $k$. Now, $g_k$ tends to $0$ as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$. In between the two "furthest" roots of $g_k$ (or, $f_k$), $g'_k = 0$ happens exactly $k-1$ times. How about the two infinite intervals outside? ;) What can you conclude by invoking its continuity and observing its limit?

Comment: Indeed. But how to show $n$ distinct real roots?

Comment: @Katoyu Indeed. Let me see.

Comment: @Katoyu Done. Please see the edit.

Comment: I see. Denote $a,b$ the smallest and largest roots of $f_k$. Then $g'(k)$ has exactly $k-1$ roots withing $(a,b)$. Since $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}g_k(x)=0$ and $g_k(a)=g_k(b)=0$, we can conclude that $g_k$ attains local max/min on $(-\infty,a)$ and $(b,\infty)$, and must attain at stationary points. This gives the other two distinct roots of $g'_k(x)$. Now everything's clear. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Exactly! I would say that you were on the right track when asking the problem!

Comment: Did you notice that your argument above only shows there are AT LEAST two distinct roots in the infinite intervals? Remember to use the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 0):

A "generic" way to do this (for arbitrary sequences of orthogonal polynomials, not just the Hermite family whose [Rodrigues formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula) you've described) is to

- derive the [recurrence relation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.2#iv),
- prove the [Christoffel–Darboux](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.2#v) formula from the recurrence relation, and
- use the Christoffel–Darboux relation and [Sturm chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem#Generalized_Sturm_chains) considerations to show that the roots of adjacent orthogonal polynomials interlace.

See Sec. 4.2, 4.3 and Thm. 4.10 in 
https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-00661847/document

Comment: Seems that this approach is way beyond the level of the course. But any way, thanks for your reply. It's good to see something new!